# Ubuntu Gnome 3 Shell custom theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I have been trying to install this theme for the last couple of hours, but I just don't get it. I just started out with Linux the other day so I am fumbling around in the dark as well.

[This is the theme](http://github.com/vivaeltopo/gnome-shell-theme-viva) I want to install.

The theme doesn't come up in Gnome tweak tool, and there's nothing to choose when I click "Shell theme" and go to one of the folders where I've copied the theme or in any of the dropdown menus

So far I've tried various different things after searching on Google.

- I've put the content (gnome-shell and resources folder and the makefile file) in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell`

  [image]
- I've put the content in the /usr/share/themes/gnome-shell-theme-viva-master

  [image]
- I've made a folder called `.theme` in my home directory and added the content

I have also tried opening a terminal in the folders and typed `make orange` but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly happens when you run `make blue` or `make orange`?

Comment: I got an error message saying; omitting directory ‘Viva/gnome-shell-theme-viva-master/gnome-shell/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of assumptions before going to the issue of this theme:

1. You have at the least installed the `gnome-shell` and `gnome-tweak-tool` packages (and considered the package `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`)
2. You have used the 'Gnome' login
3. You have opened the 'Tweak' utility and enabled user themes:

[image]

With all of this done you should be able to place your theme in `$HOME/.themes` (note 'themes' and not 'theme') as follows:

```
mkdir $HOME/.themes && cd $HOME/.themes
wget https://github.com/vivaeltopo/gnome-shell-theme-viva/archive/3.14-blue-stable.tar.gz
tar xvf 3.14-blue-stable.tar.gz
```

And certainly on my system this can now be selected in the Tweak tool:

[image]

Now this does not have the makefile switcher which seems to use `ruby-sass` and was getting a bit over the top for a non-GNOME desktop man to wrangle with but certainly the release version installs as advertised. This is the 'blue' version rather than the 'orange'...

Comment: All of the assumptions are true and the theme shows ups when I follow your instructions, but nothing happens. It doesn't change color, transparency or anything. 

Also, if I download the orange theme and place it in the folder, it doesn't show up in the tweak tool. Only the one where I followed your instructions. I tried rebooting to see if that would help, but it didn't.

Comment: I am afraid that my knowledge of these themes is limited to installation. Interesting to see if it ran on a pure gnome installation.